# Java multi-dimension array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have two dimension array of Username and Surname and able to print both Name and Surname.but I want to do below and looking for help.

1) Match name with string and output Name and Surname both

Tried with If loop but did not fails to print Surname.

if String name is give as ABC it should match with array and then print both values of Name and Surname.

```
String[][] names = {{"ABC","DEF"},{"GHI","JKL"}};

      String name = "ABC"; 

      for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {


          System.out.print(names[i][0] + ": ");

          for (int j = 1; j < names[i].length; j++) {

              System.out.print(names[i][j] + " ");

          }

          System.out.println();

          }
```

Comment: there is not `if` condition in this code above.

Comment: I do not understand the question, could you please [edit] to clarify? What exactly is the issue you are having? `ABC: DEF\nGHI: JKL` is the output I got when I ran this.

Comment: "*Match name with string and output Name and Surname both*" What?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (String[] fullName : names) {
    if (fullName[0].equals(name)) {
        for (String s : fullName) {
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

If you do not know about these for-loops: they iterate over each element in order, i.e. without having you to use an index for accessing the elements. These are the same:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    String element = array[i];
}

for (String element : array) {

}
```

Another possibility is to use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

```
String name = "ABC";

HashMap<String, String> fullNames = new HashMap<>();
fullNames.put("ABC", "DEF");
fullNames.put("GHI", "JKL");

if (fullNames.contains(name)) {
    System.out.println(name + " " + fullNames.get(name));
}
```

Comment: how does this answers the question asked by the OP.

Comment: If it doesn't, could you translate it for me to proper English? Probably misunderstood it...

Comment: `Match name with string and output Name and Surname both`, he is asking something related to matching the input with array and then printing the names. But it not completely clear.

Comment: I am not clear by myself and OP is also does not look interested into the problem. Because he has not responded yet.